# Overlay the Action bar programmatically when using the support library

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

how to overlay the action bar when using the v7 support library?
I tried the code `WindowCompat.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY` before the `setContentView()` method, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [ActionBarActivity.supportRequestWindowFeature()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html#supportRequestWindowFeature(int)) with `WindowCompat.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY` before `setContentView()`.

Comment: Sorry for late response, and it is working, thank you.